How to create a single stacked bar chart with dual y axes in excel?
I have data pertaining to price-quantity bids are sorted according to price and looks like this:

I wish to plot a single stacked bar chart, something that looks like this image of single stacked bar chart:

with price on the primary y axis and quantity on the secondary y axis. basically, i wish to find out the cleared price given the cumulative quantity demand.
I tried creating a stacked column with price and cumulative sum, switch row/column under chart design and changed the cumulative sum to secondary axis. however, i can never get a single stacked bar chart. i tried setting overlap to 100% and gap width to 0% as well, but i still get this:


I assume this is what you want:

As you can see you need to restructure your input data range.
Also look at :

Where series1 Looks like :

And as you already figered out:


is there anyway to do this automatically? seems like this requires quite a lot of manual actions. my dataset involved over 100 price quantity bids so choosing the series one by one is not feasible
i will have to do the series one by one and check secondary axis for all cumulative quantities.
thanks for ur help and detailed explanation, really appreciate it!

also, i dont wish for price to be cumulative, just as a point of ref. thanks!

would it be possible to get something like this?
https://pasteboard.co/bWXI9wezKJLZ.png
